Auto adjust in the middle text in bar
I have a data frame called df :

df = tibble(var =c("A","B","C","D","E"), val = c(2,8,9,1,5) );df


resulting to :
 var     val
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         2
2 B         8
3 C         9
4 D         1
5 E         5

I want to plot horizontally the bars of the val column and the value of each category to be in text in the middle of the bar.
ggplot(df, aes(x = var, y = val)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "lightgrey") +
  coord_flip() + # This flips the coordinates to make the bars horizontal
  geom_text(aes(label = val))

resulting to:

How can I put the values (text) automatically in the middle of the horizontal bar ?

You can put the labels into the middle of the bars using position = position_stack(vjust = .5):
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = val, y = var)) +
  geom_bar(
    stat = "identity",
    fill = "lightgrey"
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = val),
    position = position_stack(vjust = .5)
  )



Divide by 2:
ggplot(df, aes(x = var, y = val)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "lightgrey") +
  geom_text(aes(x = var, y = val/2, label = val)) +
  coord_flip()



In base
X = data.frame(var =c("A","B","C","D","E"), val = c(2,8,9,1,5))
with(X, { barplot(val, horiz=TRUE, names.arg=var, las=2L, xaxt="n") |>
    text(x=val/2L, labels=val)
    axis(side=1L, at=seq(0L, max(X$val), 2.5)) })


